# Show a string in multiple TextViews in adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, watson-assistant

My App currently displays 4 options (which I want to make clickable) in a single TextView. At the moment, it looks like this (i.e. last message bubble): [app picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83mgc.png)

Instead of the above, I want to have those options as 4 separate TextViews, like [in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28dQG.png). I researched multiple solutions, but none of them worked for me, because I am using `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Here is the relevant part:

```
 case OPTION:

            String option = "";
            option = message.getMessage();
            for ( DialogNodeOutputOptionsElement r : message.getOptions() ){
                 option += r.getLabel()+"<br/>";
                ((ViewHolder) holder).message.setText(Html.fromHtml(option));
                // new TextView for next Option
```

The whole ChatAdapter looks like this:

```
    public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    protected Activity activity;
    private int SELF = 100;
    private ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList;



    public ChatAdapter(ArrayList<Message> messageArrayList) {
        this.messageArrayList = messageArrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;

        // view type is to identify where to render the chat message
        // left or right
        if (viewType == SELF) {
            // self message
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.chat_item_self, parent, false);
        } else {
            // WatBot message
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.chat_item_watson, parent, false);
        }


        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);
        if (message.getId() != null && message.getId().equals("1")) {
            return SELF;
        }

        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messageArrayList.get(position);
        switch (message.type) {
            case TEXT:
                ((ViewHolder) holder).message.setText(Html.fromHtml(message.getMessage()+"<br/>"));

                    break;
            case IMAGE:
                ((ViewHolder) holder).message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ImageView iv = ((ViewHolder) holder).image;
                Glide
                        .with(iv.getContext())
                        .load(message.getUrl())
                        .into(iv);
                break;
            case OPTION:

                String option = "";
                option = message.getMessage();
                for ( DialogNodeOutputOptionsElement r : message.getOptions() ){
                     option += r.getLabel()+"<br/>";
                    ((ViewHolder) holder).message.setText(Html.fromHtml(option));
                    // new TextView for next Option



                }
                break;
            case PAUSE:break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView message;
        ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);




            //TODO: Uncomment this if you want to use a custom Font
            
        }
    }


}
```

and the XML looks like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/new_face" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bubble_watbot"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

[Contex Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvNib.png)

[App picture after working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrOh1.png)

Comment: can you please add the `xml` layout of the item corresponding to your `ViewHolder`? Ideally, add code of your `Adapter` and `ViewHolder` as well.

Comment: @DatPhamTat added it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following:

Inside your layout, add a container for your to-be-added `TextView`s:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear"... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView ... />

    <TextView ... />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/optionsContainer"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@drawable/bg_bubble_watbot"
                  android:orientation="vertical" />

    <ImageView .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, update your `ViewHolder` to reference the container:

```java
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
    LinearLayout optionsContainer;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ...
        optionsContainer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.optionsContainer);
    }
}
```

Then, in your `OPTION` case:

```java
    TextView tv = ((ViewHolder) holder).message;
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE));
    LinearLayout optionsContainer = ((ViewHolder) holder).optionsContainer;
    TextView messageTextView = createTextView(message.getMessage(), optionsContainer.getContext());
    for ( DialogNodeOutputOptionsElement r : message.getOptions() ) {
        // you should check if r.getLabel() really returns a HTML string
        // if not, you will have to enclose it with html tags to make it clickable later
        String option = r.getLabel();
        TextView optionTextView = createTextView(option, optionsContainer.getContext());
        // add the created textView to our container
        optionsContainer.addView(optionTextView);
    }
```

Implement the `createTextView()` function inside your adapter:

```java
private TextView createTextView(String text, Context context) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            ((int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int) LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params);
    tv.setTextSize((float) 15);
    tv.setText(text);
    int blueColor = Color.parseColor("#0000ff");
    // make text blue
    tv.setTextColor(blueColor);
    // make text underline
    tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Link clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // add here what the click should do
        }
    });
    return tv;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and your solution. Its still throws me an error on '    TextView tv = new TextView(context); ' It can not resolve the context in this statement. As well in '    TextView optionTextView = createTextView(option, optionsContainer.context);' Same problem

Comment: Change the `optionsContainer.context` to `optionsContainer.getContext()`. I mixed a bit of kotlin in there, sorry.

Comment: I put a picture below my post with Context Error.

Comment: You imported wrong `Context` class. Go up to your imports, remove `com.ibm...Context`, and add `android.content.Context` instead

Comment: Its working now, but I don't now how you wanted it to look like. It doesnt show the starting text now, like it did before and the Options are getting displayed almost the same way, except there not in the bubble anymore.. Picture in the post

Comment: There is no bubble because the container was missing the `@drawable/bg_bubble_watbot` background. It doesn't show the starting text because I forgot to add the starting text. These things you could figure out yourself though, they seem quite trivial. I have updated my answer, look for changes in the layout and the `OPTION` case. The texts don't appear as links because probably your `r.getLabel()` does not return a HTML text, but just a plain text, I mentioned it in the comments above the code. Please add an example of what your `r.getLabel()` returns.

Comment: Thank you for help! I think I got it from here and `r.getLabel()` return a JSON Object from Watson Assistant and the `Options` are not HTML links they are just clickable Options which follow up with a new Dialog in Watson Assistant. Sry for the misunderstanding

Comment: I see. I updated the `createTextView()` function to make text blue and underlined, and clickable. Just add your own click logic.